# Consume a Java Web Service through a C# Service Reference

Tags: c#, java, web-services, web-config, wcf-binding

There are many questions about how to do this using a Web Reference in C#, but I know how to do that.  What I'm trying to accomplish is to have a portable dll that consumes the Java Web Services that I can reference in my projects instead of duplicating the functionality.  One of the things is that with Web References the `KeepAlive` of the request is set to `true`.  That doesn't work for the environment I'm developing in and it has to be `false`.  What I did with Web References is create an abstract class that inherits `SoapHttpClientProtocol` and change the Reference.cs to inherit from the abstract class.  The abstract class looked like this:

```
[System.Web.Services.WebServiceBinding(Name = "JavaWebReferenceProxy")]
public abstract class JavaWebReferenceProxy : SoapHttpClientProtocol
{
    public JavaWebReferenceProxy()
    {
        base.Timeout = Settings.Instance.SoapTimeout;
    }

    protected override WebRequest GetWebRequest(Uri uri)
    {
        WebRequest rq = base.GetWebRequest(uri);
        ((HttpWebRequest)rq).KeepAlive = Settings.Instance.SoapKeepAlive;

        return rq;
    }
}
```

This allowed me to override the `GetWebRequest` and the constructor to set values that were in the web.config.  I'm wondering how I can do this with a Service Reference to the Java Web Service.  I've found some examples for the simplified `serviceModel` section in 4.0 (which is the framework I'm using), but I need to specify the url and the timeout as well.  I'm not sure if I can use the simplified `serviceModel` or if I need to use the full implementation.  I also am unsure if I can use the Service Reference at all.  I'm just looking for a little guidance if anyone has implemented something like this.

What should the `serviceModel` section look like in my config file?  The 3 things I need to be able to specify is the URL, the Timeout and the keep-alive.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need custom binding for that. Try this:

```
<system.serviceModel>
  <bindings>
    <customBinding>
      <binding name="myBinding" sendTimout="00:05:00">
        <textMessageEncoding messageVersion="Soap11" />
        <httpTransport keepAliveEnabled="false" />
      </binding>
    </customBinding>
  </bindings>
  <client>
    <endpoint name="myEndpointName" address="http://..." binding="customBinding" 
              bindingConfiguration="myBinding" contract="MyReference.IMyService" />
  </client>
</system.serviceModel>
```

SendTimeout should set timeout for operation completion (including receiving response), keepAliveEnebled controls persistent HTTP connection and address in edpoint is address of the service.

Comment: I had to increase the size of the readerQuotas but this worked perfectly.  Thanks so much for the help!